# Oracle 11g listener doesnt work with ip

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a server with two NICs, Hyper-V and an Oracle 11g db (I know, on a Hyper-V host dont run other servives ...).

One NIC has the IP 192.168.100.1 and the other NIC I use for a vswitch in Hyper-V. So the vNIC in the network settings has no IP set (just DHCP address 169.*). The VM is running well and has internet link.
The problem is, that as soon as both NICs are active, the progeam medistar cant reach the oracle 11g db. This problem already exists even before the server has been a hyper-v host. As soon as the second NIC is activated, app cant connect to 11g db.
The listener.ora file looks like this:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server-1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\oracle
```

If I change Server-1 to the IP 192.168.100.1, it doesnt work. What else can I do? :(
I then get the error ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: What is the app connecting to, and what error does it get when it can't connect? Does whatever host name it is using always resolve to the right address too? The `lsnrctl` output (with and without the second NIC active) will be useful, but also does the DB have `local_listener` set?

Comment: I just added a IP address to the other NIC and restarted the service, now he can find the db and even the VMs work. Thx for your support.